# Use CASE or REPLACE for my conditional Query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables on which join is there.

for second table TableB i am fetching both id and post.

```
SELECT a.id,
    a.NAME,
    b.id,
    b.post
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.bid = b.id
```

But in one case **b.id=3** i have **post ='manager'** but i have to show **post='associate manager'**. i cannot change table values but only query.

I am currently using replace .

```
SELECT a.id,
    a.NAME,
    b.id,
    replace(b.post, 'manager', 'associate manager')
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.bid = b.id
```

Should i switch to case or this is correct.

Regards,

Comment: Can you show us some sample data? I think a CASE statement would be better, but depends on what logic you want to apply to it (how you determine what value to display).

Comment: case makes more sense here.  replace will replace any entry containing manager with associate manager.  so if you have a post called `managers` or `all manager` they would be changed as well. to `associate managers` and `all associate manager`  Replace changes all occurances.  case will only replace exact match of `manager`

Comment: currently i don't have only like manager' but still CASE look'S more cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Case Statement`

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.NAME,
       b.id,
       CASE
         WHEN b.id = 3 THEN 'associate manager'
         ELSE post
       END
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
               ON a.bid = b.id
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to say your answer is correct. Based on the details provided, it will work, but I think there's more to the bigger picture. I think waiting until the OP gives more details would make more sense.